# (Apparent) Paradoxes in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, soft-question, education

I find that studying the paradoxes of special relativity, such as the twin paradox, ladder paradox, and Ehrenfest paradox, and their resolutions, helps me to understand it.

Are there any similarly helpful paradoxes in General Relativity?

Comment: I see that we have a big-list tag, but the tag's text says not to use it. Is the closure basically because this is a big-list type question, which is no longer allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Submarine paradox***

- J. M. Supplee, Am. J. Phys. 57, 75 (1989).
- Matsas, 2008,
  http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0305106
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplee%27s_paradox

A submarine is neutrally buoyant at rest. There is a contradiction when it then starts to move, since an observer in the water's frame says it sinks due to its increased density, while sailors say it rises due to water's greater density.

***Tethered galaxies***

Suppose two galaxies are tied together with a rigid cable. What happens due to cosmological expansion? What happens to the Doppler shift of the galaxy?

- Davis, Lineweaver, and Webb, https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0104349
- Clavering, https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0511709

***Straddling the horizon***

What happens if you have half your body on one side of a black hole's event horizon, and half on the other side?

Comment: Does the hole argument count, as well?